# How to instantiate a new view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController with two UIButtons and UIlabels.

In order to make similar ViewController of this, I would like to instantiate a new view controller programmatically
like this.

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main")
```

Then navigate to the view controller like this:

```
navigationcontroller?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I have set StoryBoard ID as `"Main"`, however I do not know where I can write these codes.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
    let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")

        @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var yourButton1: customButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var yourButton2: customButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            label1.text = "Hello1"
            label2.text = "Hello2"
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

   func player(url: URL) {
        do {
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
            player.play()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

   @IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
       player(url: url1)
    }

    @IBAction func pushButton2(sender: UIButton) {
       player(url: url2)
    }
        }
```

tableView

```
   class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var names = [String]()
    var identities = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        names = ["name1","name2","name3","name4"]
        identities = ["Main","Main2","Main3","Main4"]

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = "\(names[indexPath.row])"

        return cell!
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let ViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController!, animated: true)
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use a segue to connect the UIButtons to the next ViewController?

Comment: What event do you want to trigger the display of this new view controller? Put the code in your question in whatever place handles that event.

Comment: I need to create many similar ViewController and I found that it is more efficient with code.

Comment: @ rmaddy I want to create  ViewController with UIbuttons that plays audio file when selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set Storyboard ID value for the view controller in storyboard and use it here:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistrationController")
navigationcontroller?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

[image]

### Edit:

```
var urls1 = [String]()
var urls2 = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    names = ["name1","name2","name3","name4"]
    identities = ["A","B","C","D"]
    urls1 = ["url1","url2" ....]
    urls2 = ["url1","url2" ....]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let url1 = urls1[indexPath.row]
    let url2 = urls2[indexPath.row]

//let ViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName) this is wrong you only have one viewcontroller on storyboard and its storyboard id is fixed.

    let viewController: ViewController  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoryboardID") as! ViewController

    viewController.url1 = url1
    viewController.url2 = url2

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

---

Comment: Where can I write this code? let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerStoryboardID")

Comment: From the previous controller!! Do you have a list of url or items that are displayed on screen? Do you use table view? where do you store those url?  add that code to your question.

Comment: Yes I use tableViews I added my code. To be honest, I do not know where to store my url. I thought I will have to write it in each ViewController!

Comment: Thanks I will try it !!

Comment: I implemented your code but receiving two errors. viewController.url1 = url1 "cannnot assign to property url1 is a let constant"

Comment: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewController!, animated: true)
"cannot convert value type of "viewcontrollertype" to expected argument type "UIViewController" "

Comment: let url1 to var url1 and go to stoaryboard select your player controller and set the controller class in the right panel to ViewController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136694/discussion-between-johncole-and-hasan83).