# Xcode Swift - Pass Button Path Data Between View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, viewcontroller

My app has a category of things so when I press "Burger" button on my home viewcontroller it takes me to secondviewcontroller with more options (Buttons) like "spicy, mild, Fire". what I want to do is I want to save path of those button clicked on thirdviewcontroller as text.

For example on thirdviewcontroller a text says "Burger -> Spicy" or "Burger -> mind"
make sure I'm dealing with the button pressed in the path and not text entered.

How do I do that

Comment: search dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to keep two variables in the second and third view controller.

```
class FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc2 = ...// instantiate second view controller
        vc2.textVal = sender.titleLabel!.text
        //present vc2
    }
}
```

Then in the second view controller get the text of the button and set it in a text

```
class SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var textVal: String?
    
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc3 = ...// instantiate thrid view controller
        let buttonText = sender.titleLabel!.text
        vc3.textVal = "\(textVal) -> \(buttonText)"
        //present vc3
    }
}
```

Now in the third view controller set the label's text

```
class ThridViewController : UIViewController {
    
    var textVal: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        lblText.text = textVal
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it's not working! multiple errors. i think the method is really right but code  wise i think there is problem

Comment: I didn't write full code here, just the prototype, you need to instantiate 2nd and 3rd view controller, then you have to present/push view controller. Do that for yourself. I just want to show you how to pass buttons data from one view controller to another.

Comment: sorry im so a beginner to this that i do not even understand that much

Comment: then look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035984/instantiate-and-present-a-viewcontroller-in-swift) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470334/how-to-instantiate-a-new-view-controller-programmatically) answer for how to instantiate & present/push view controller.